# Magento 2: How to Reauthorize Paypal payment & store all information

Tags: magento2, custom, payment-methods, paypal, magento2.1.6

I have tried below code

Override `callDoReauthorization` as it has issue with original https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9336

```
magento\app\code\Custom\Module\Model\Api\Nvp.php

class Nvp extends \Magento\Paypal\Model\Api\Nvp {

    public function callDoReauthorization() {
        $request = $this->_exportToRequest($this->_doReauthorizationRequest);
        $response = $this->call('DoReauthorization', $request); // Sample Response As Below
        $this->_importFromResponse($this->_paymentInformationResponse, $response);
        $this->_importFromResponse($this->_doReauthorizationResponse, $response);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Sample Response for Reauthorization

```
    $response = array(
        'AUTHORIZATIONID' => '45610683DL9281543', // Reauthorization Id of Transaction Id 8F998724VR277443T
        'TIMESTAMP' => '2017-04-28T01:20:31Z',
        'CORRELATIONID' => '5a5a4056b1d7',
        'ACK' => 'Success',
        'VERSION' => '72.0',
        'BUILD' => '32996991',
        'PAYMENTSTATUS' => 'Pending',
        'PENDINGREASON' => 'authorization',
        'PROTECTIONELIGIBILITY' => 'Eligible',
        'PROTECTIONELIGIBILITYTYPE' => 'ItemNotReceivedEligible, UnauthorizedPaymentEligible'
    );
```

For Reauthorization taking reference of `magento\vendor\magento\module-paypal\Model\Express.php` function `_callDoAuthorize`.

**Reauthorization Code which I tried as below**

```
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$proFactory = $objectManager->get('Magento\Paypal\Model\ProFactory');
$checkoutSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Checkout\Model\Session'); // Not sure required or not in reauth
$pro = $proFactory->create();
$pro->setMethod(\Magento\Paypal\Model\Config::METHOD_WPP_EXPRESS);
$apiData = $pro->getApi()->getData();
foreach ($apiData as $k => $v) {
    if (is_object($v)) {
        unset($apiData[$k]);
    }
}

$checkoutSession->setPaypalTransactionData($apiData);
$pro->resetApi();

$api = _setApiProcessableErrors($pro)
                    ->setAmount('78.00')
                    ->setCurrencyCode('SGD')
                    ->setAuthorizationId('8F998724VR277443T')
                    ->callDoReauthorization();

echo $api->getAuthorizationId();
exit;
```

`_setApiProcessableErrors` will use `magento\vendor\magento\module-paypal\Model\Express.php` function.

We need to make entry in `sales_payment_transaction`  & `sales_order_status_history` table.

When I'm using https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#authorization_get it's not giving `valid_untill` & all details.

It is not updating `Authorisation Expiry Date:` for Same Transaction in Sandbox as well.

Reauthorization API is not working : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43583789/paypal-unable-to-reauthorize-authorized-payment-error-an-internal-service-err